# How to invoke the base and overloaded constructors at the same time?

Tags: c#

I want to invoke the overloaded ctor via `this` and the base ctor via `base` as follows.

```
public Child(string msg, DateTime dt) : base(msg, dt), this(msg)
    => WriteLine($"Child at {dt.Second}");
```

Apparently it will not compile.

## Question

How to invoke both? Is it impossible?
Note that I am not asking how to invoke the contents of the corresponding ctors by rearranging them.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

class Parent
{
    public Parent(string msg)
        => WriteLine($"Parent {msg}");

    public Parent(string msg, DateTime dt) : this(msg)
        => WriteLine($"Parent at {dt.Second}");
}
class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(string msg) : base(msg)
        => WriteLine($"Child {msg}");

    public Child(string msg, DateTime dt) : base(msg, dt)//, this(msg)
        => WriteLine($"Child at {dt.Second}");
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
        => new Child("hi", DateTime.Now);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is impossible. There is no such construct in C#. The reason is that a constructor *always* invokes the base's constructor; when there is no specific constructor denoted by `base(…)`, the default constructor is invoked.

However, a simple private method will serve the same purpose:

```
class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(string msg) : base(msg)
        => ChildInit(msg);

    public Child(string msg, DateTime dt) : base(msg, dt)
    {
        ChildInit(msg);
        WriteLine($"Child at {dt.Second}");
    }

    private void ChildInit(string msg)
        => WriteLine($"Child {msg}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a off-bet, but maybe the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) could help you? Basically you do not get public constructors, but a static function to create instances.

The issue is that there is clearly a lot of logic in the Constructors. Possibly too much logic. There are 2 common reasons to use the Factory pattern:

- you want to get to the singleton pattern. Factory there is simply the stepping stone you have to take.
- there is work that needs to be done that is at the same time: too complex for the class user, too complex for the constructor and has to be done at runtime

The constructor by nature is not a normal function. And that non-normality might get in the way. Factory Functions in turn are just run-of-the-mill static functions, that can be called whenever and however you want. And a class can be it's own Factory by providing it's own Factory function.

However while I can not name it, I can not shake the feeling this getting around the limitations might be a bad idea. Usually those limitations are there for the reason you only realize **after** it is way to late to change your path. And type safety is not a thing I normally touch at all.